# How do I compare two different values from a dropdown/select menu and apply it to a conditional statement as one value?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a small calculator which asks the user for their month and date of birth and gives them the astrology sign according to the values they selected. I'm just not quite sure how to combine the two values into one so I can assign it to a variable.

JS:

```
    function getSelectValues() {
    var selectedMonth = document.getElementById("month").value;
    var selectedDate = document.getElementById("date").value;
    return selectedMonth + selectedDate;
}

getSelectValues();
```

HTML:

```
    <form id="birthday">
<select id="month">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
    <option value="March">March</option>
    <option value="April">April</option>
    <option value="May">May</option>
    <option value="June">June</option>
    <option value="July">July</option>
    <option value="August">August</option>
    <option value="September">September</option>
    <option value="October">October</option>
    <option value="November">November</option>
    <option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select id="date">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1st">1</option>
    <option value="2nd">2</option>
    <option value="3rd">3</option>
    <option value="4th">4</option>
    <option value="5th">5</option>
    <option value="6th">6</option>
    <option value="7th">7</option>
    <option value="8th">8</option>
    <option value="9th">9</option>
    <option value="10th">10</option>
    <option value="11th">12</option>
    <option value="12th">12</option>
    <option value="13th">13</option>
    <option value="14th">14</option>
    <option value="15th">15</option>
    <option value="16th">16</option>
    <option value="17th">17</option>
    <option value="18th">18</option>
    <option value="19th">19</option>
    <option value="20th">20</option>
    <option value="21st">21</option>
    <option value="22nd">22</option>
    <option value="23rd">23</option>
    <option value="24th">24</option>
    <option value="25th">25</option>
    <option value="26th">26</option>
    <option value="27th">27</option>    
    <option value="28th">28</option>
    <option value="29th">29</option>
    <option value="30th">30</option>
    <option value="31st">31</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" id="button" value="Go"></input>
```

Comment: What you're doing should actually work, although it'll make it harder to break the resulting string apart to get the month and day separately. You'd be better off putting a separator like `-` or `/` (or anything, really) between them. But better still, why not keep them as separate variables, or add them as separate elements of one object or array? [EDIT: just realised you're not doing anything with the result of the function call - you should assign that to a variable in order to be able to work with it.]

Comment: Let me know if you need something other than my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This looks at the `selectedIndex` for the day/month values and then checks them against the Aries sign range as an example. Remember in JavaScript dates January is 0 not 1.

```js
function getSelectValues() {
  var selectedMonth = document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex - 1;
  var selectedDate = document.getElementById("date").selectedIndex;
  var d = new Date(0000, selectedMonth, selectedDate);
  var ariesStr = new Date(0000, 2, 21)
  var ariesEnd = new Date(0000, 3, 19) 
  console.log(ariesStr < d && d < ariesEnd)
}
```

```html
<select id="month">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="January">January</option>
  <option value="February">February</option>
  <option value="March">March</option>
  <option value="April">April</option>
  <option value="May">May</option>
  <option value="June">June</option>
  <option value="July">July</option>
  <option value="August">August</option>
  <option value="September">September</option>
  <option value="October">October</option>
  <option value="November">November</option>
  <option value="December">December</option>
</select>
<select id="date">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1st">1</option>
  <option value="2nd">2</option>
  <option value="3rd">3</option>
  <option value="4th">4</option>
  <option value="5th">5</option>
  <option value="6th">6</option>
  <option value="7th">7</option>
  <option value="8th">8</option>
  <option value="9th">9</option>
  <option value="10th">10</option>
  <option value="11th">12</option>
  <option value="12th">12</option>
  <option value="13th">13</option>
  <option value="14th">14</option>
  <option value="15th">15</option>
  <option value="16th">16</option>
  <option value="17th">17</option>
  <option value="18th">18</option>
  <option value="19th">19</option>
  <option value="20th">20</option>
  <option value="21st">21</option>
  <option value="22nd">22</option>
  <option value="23rd">23</option>
  <option value="24th">24</option>
  <option value="25th">25</option>
  <option value="26th">26</option>
  <option value="27th">27</option>
  <option value="28th">28</option>
  <option value="29th">29</option>
  <option value="30th">30</option>
  <option value="31st">31</option>
</select>
<input type="button" onclick="getSelectValues()" id="button" value="Go">
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you're planning to check which sign they are, but it might actually be easier to keep the month and day separate. Then a simple way to check signs would be like:

```
const months = {
  mar : { 
    cutoff: 21,
    oneSign: picses,
    otherSign: aries 
  },
  jul : {
    cutoff: 23,
    oneSign: cancer,
    otherSign: leo 
  },
  oct : { 
    cutoff: 22,
    oneSign: scorpio,
    otherSign: sagittarius
  }
}  

function getSign(month, day){
  if(day < months[month][cutoff]){ return months[month][oneSign]; }
  else { return months[month][otherSign]; }
}
```